# How to print multiple row of data in Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Problem : I don't know how to print multiple rows of data from my mySQL database in Jasper Reports. I think I should create a loop in the jrxml file but I don't know how.

Basically, I need to print all the data in my database. 
I would really appreciate any help from you guys, thanks.

Here's the code in the jrxml file :
(I removed the top part because it keeps my code from being fully shown here)

```
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[select * from employeelist_table]]>
</queryString>
<field name="EMPLOYEE_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="EMPLOYEE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SURNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="FIRSTNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="MIDDLE_INITIAL" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="DEPARTMENT" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="POSITION" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="GENDER" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="BIRTHDATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ADDRESS" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CONTACT_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SSS_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="BASIC_PAY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ALLOWANCE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="LEAVE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="NO_WORK" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="DAY_RATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="OVERTIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="GROSSPAY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="NETPAY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="DAY_ABSENT" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="LATE_UNDERTIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SSS_PREMIUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="PHILHEALTH" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="WTAX" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="RBNI_LOAN" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SSS_LOAN" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TOTAL_DEDUCTION" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="28" y="11" width="255" height="57"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Jaybeeh\\Documents\\Computerized_Payroll_System\\src\\computerized_payroll_system\\logo2.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="92" y="20" width="159" height="48"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[WESTERN COLLEGE, INC.   NAIC, CAVITE                                  PAYROLL SUMMARY]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="33" y="2" width="82" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[EMPLOYEE_ID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="127" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[EMPLOYEE_NAME]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="240" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[DEPARTMENT]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="354" y="2" width="68" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[BASIC_PAY]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="432" y="2" width="59" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[SSS_LOAN]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="501" y="2" width="65" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[RBNI_LOAN]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="578" y="2" width="48" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[WTAX]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="639" y="2" width="66" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[GROSSPAY]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="724" y="2" width="63" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[NETPAY]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="63" y="0" width="29" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPLOYEE_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="127" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPLOYEE_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DEPARTMENT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="354" y="0" width="68" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{BASIC_PAY}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="432" y="0" width="59" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SSS_LOAN}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="501" y="0" width="65" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RBNI_LOAN}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="578" y="0" width="48" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WTAX}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="639" y="0" width="66" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GROSSPAY}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="724" y="0" width="63" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NETPAY}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

Comment: You can start with [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf). Samples are [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you want to print multiple rows of data in a JasperReport under some fields, put those fields in the **Detail band of the report.** ***The detail band is executed for each row returned in the resultset.*** As such you can print n number of rows in the jasper Report. You don't have to put any kind of loop in jrxml or in the jasper report.

Detail band is ideally suited for repetitive tasks such as printing multiple rows from database in the report.

Other way is to group the data and print the data in the Table. The table uses its own dataset and you can define the query which will return multiple rows and feed the output of this query to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any loop here  loop in the jrxml file. The detail band is iterative and will automatically loop depending on the number of row returned. I hope you are using the Ireport designer. So make sure that ireport is successfully connected to the database. Which error message is returned whenever you compile or preview your report ?